# How to force decimals in flutter's Numberformat.compactCurreny?

Tags: flutter, dart, currency, number-formatting

I'm trying to get a human comprehensive monetary value.

Being that value 100000 it returns 100K
Being that value 100500 it returns 101K when I would like to get 100.5K

Note that I'm using the intl number format because I expect to be able to send in the locale and get the proper parsing of dots and commas for different regions

Here's the snipped of code I'm running:

```
  double amount = 100500;
  String currency = "EUR";
  String locale = "en-US";

  NumberFormat.compactCurrency(
    locale: locale,
    name: currency,
    symbol: "",
    decimalDigits: 1,
  ).format(amount);
```

Seems that calling for `compactCurrency` basically compacts the number to a 3 character string so it ceils/floors the value instead of showing the decimals corresponding to it

Is there any solution to this behavior? I've seen the option of creating a new locale setting but that's not really an elegant solution as this is used to display different patterns per locale and would have to maintain the separators logic and everything.

Comment: Can you explain what is NumberFormat? Is it your custom class or is it some kinda package? If it is your custom class then provide code for that custom class of it is a package then tell us what package

Comment: @LonelyWolf eeeehm... sure https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html it is a native part of flutter

Comment: All right.. It is part of external intl package. You have to install it so it is not native really. Never mind... I have tried that and even though I've never worked with that package I'm sure there isn't much you can do about it unless you find a better package which do the job or create your own custom class for that... Sorry for not being very helpful. Maybe someone else will answer it. I would suggest you to put bounty on this question. Good question though.. Vote up from me.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time with it @LonelyWolf will see if there's luck. I've found ways to declare my own locale implementation but then I'll need to keep track of what is the locale the user is using and cloning it and then modify those values I want, a bit of a nightmare implementation

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute `maximumFractionDigits` does the trick:

```dart
  double amount = 100500;
  String currency = "EUR";
  String locale = "en-US";

  (NumberFormat.compactCurrency(
      locale: locale,
      name: currency,
      symbol: "",
      decimalDigits: 1,
    )..maximumFractionDigits = 1)
        .format(amount);
// = '100.5K'
```